# Servlet method is called twice on Android browser

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to write a downloader servlet. I got some problems as I mentioned on this topic : [Why it throws Write Failed exceptions on my FileServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903846/why-it-throws-write-failed-exceptions-on-my-fileservlet) and I noticed that my doGet() method is called twice when I use android device and its browser.

I tested it in computer, firefox chrome and explorer and saw that it is called once. However when I use mobile device it is called twice.

How can I solve this problem ? what difference between calling a servlet method by mobile device and a computer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try testing a manual HTTP `HEAD` request (e.g., using **`curl`**) and see whether that triggers `goGet()`. If yes, then probably you are seeing a `HEAD` followed by a `GET`.

Comment: I checked access logs of my web server, almost all requests are "GET". Not any "HEAD"..

Comment: Again, I would suggest that you test it yourself, rather than relying solely upon the log output. Your Web server or Web app container might be translating `HEAD` to `GET` for your servlet, for example.

Comment: Now I checked with curl and send a HEAD request. my doGet method is triggered. How can I handle this ?

Comment: That I cannot help you with, as it has been a decade or so since I last wrote a servlet.

Comment: @anL : I am facing the same problem ... if u have solution then  let me know